# pass dynamic data to jqplot piechart in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqplot, pie-chart

i want to display a jqplot piechart, im able to display it with static data, but i want to display with dynamic data from database..for that, i connected to my database and and binded the data  to a list and now how can i call that list from my view?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [
['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
];
 var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], 
  { 
   seriesDefaults: {
    // Make this a pie chart.
    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
    rendererOptions: {
      // Put data labels on the pie slices.
      // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
      showDataLabels: true
    }
  }, 
  legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
  }
  );
  });
```

, now my requirement is to display the same data from the database and i binded this data to a list in my controller and now how can i call that list from my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using MVC you can put all that data in your model with the list of key vale pair and then convert it to JSON while passing it to javascript.
 and if you want this to be done via ajax then you can send the request to json and get a JSON result from the Action method of controller.

Use Javascript serializer to convert the model to Json in your action method

```
var data = somedata_with_KeyValuePair;
var model = new MyModel();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
model.JsonData = serializer.Serialize(data);
return View(model);
```

and then use it like this

```
var data = <%= Model.JsonData %>
```

or if you are  using MVC 3 then following can work as well

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(YourObjectContaingListOfKeyValue)) seems to do the trick.
```